# initializing firebase cloud messaging without google-services plugin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

due to some reasons i've decided to initialize firebase sdk without aplying the google-service plugin and addin the google-services.json file to project.

here is my code in the application class

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
setApiKey("val").setProjectId("val").
setDatabaseUrl("val").setApplicationId("val").setGcmSenderId("val").setStorageBucket("val").build());
```

and in my build.gradle i've added this

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
```

the firebase console does'nt show me any installation after the app is installed, but when i send a cloud mesage using console, it show me the number of devices installed app!,(and also the notification does'nt recieve)

Comment: When you send notification from firebase console, it is received only when the app is in the background. To receive notifications even when the app is in the foreground, you will need to create a notification yourself inside `onMessageReceived` of your FCM service class. Go though the docs for more.

Comment: yes i know that, and i have that service as the docs, but the device does'nt receive notification even when the app is in background, also the console does not update the installed number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, and the answer to your problem is very easy: You have to call to:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(...
```

in your own custom Application's onCreate() method, for example:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, new FirebaseOptions.Builder().
                    setApiKey("val").
                    setProjectId("val").
                    setDatabaseUrl("val").
                    setApplicationId("val").
                    setGcmSenderId("val").
                    setStorageBucket("val").build());
        }
    }
```

Why? Regarding what this [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html) and this [post](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application) says about how to have multiple firebase projects and you are not using google-services.json and google-services plugin, your firebase instance is not being initialized and you should initialize it as any other framework in your own custom application class in order to have it at the moment to receive a push notification.

Answer (score -3):

This is not good idea to send cloud messaging without google-services plugin. All your keys inside to Google services json and when you want to send notification to your app, firebase will use this keys. May, if you add in strings.xml your keys, will work but also this not good idea.

Please read this doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: The only thing google-services plugin does is actually adding those keys to strings.xml. You can check it by decompiling the APK and strings.xml. So it doesn't matter if you use the plugin or not

Comment: It's totally OK to go without google-services as explained by Sam Stern (from Google): https://medium.com/@samstern_58566/how-to-use-firebase-on-android-without-the-google-services-plugin-93ecc7dc6c4